# How to kill process by name in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, process, uwp-xaml

> How to kill process from task manager using UWP ? i cannot use
>   following code to get process by process name:

```
  using (Process myProcess = new Process())
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to kill process by name in UWP C#?

Please check [**UWP App Diagnostics**](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/) blog. UWP provide new APIs designed to provide diagnostic information about running apps. And you could use [`StartTerminateAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startterminateasync#Windows_System_AppResourceGroupInfo_StartTerminateAsync) method to stop the running app. And this is [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/UWPTaskMonitor) please check.